# Finding the last element of the item in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I work about C++ project on Visual studio. I have more code normally but I prepared simple basic example of my code for you:

```
void printArray(string theArray[], int sizeOfArray);

int main()
{
   string data[] = { "Hi","my","name","is","John"};

   int num_elements = sizeof(data) / sizeof(data[0]);

   printArray(data, num_elements);

   system("PAUSE");
   return 0;
}

void printArray(string theArray[], int sizeOfArray) {
   for (int x = 0; x < sizeOfArray; x++) {
      cout << theArray[x] << endl;
    }
}
```

So, Is there any way to find last item on the array?
My expected output looks only `John`

Comment: there is a simple relation between the number of elements and the index of the last element... I dont want to spoil the exercise...

Comment: @one liner , thanks for answer but I can't use third party in my project.

Comment: `std::vector` is not "third party"

Comment: @Asell You use `std::string`.  Is that "third-party"?

Comment: @user463035818 I can't use `<char>` or something like that in my project.

Comment: So why usage of `std::string` is ok, but usage of `std::vector` isn't ok?  They're both containers.  In a non-trivial program, passing arrays and a separate size is susceptible to all sorts of bugs appearing.  I guess producing code that can lead to bugs is now part of the C++ curriculum.

Comment: you have to explain. `char` is the most basic type. If you cannot use that then even a c-alike approach (your code) is not possible as `std::string` is just as part of the standard library as `std::vector` and it does use `char` (its basically just an alias for `std::basic_string<char>`

Comment: I'm pretty sure you misunderstood the prof because you thought `std::vector` is third-party.

Comment: The last item in a vector (if it isn't empty)?  `vector.back()`.  No bugs, no need to calculate anything using `sizeof()` -- it just works.  And since you're using `std::string`, it also has a `back()` function.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of this:

```
for (int x = 0; x < sizeOfArray; x++) {
    cout << theArray[x] << endl;
}
```

You could simply put this:

```
cout << theArray[sizeOfArray - 1] << endl;
```

There's no need for the loop if you just want to print one element.

Comment: thank you for your effort @Blaze it helped me a lot. I'm new on C++

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `std::vector` instead of an array and `std::vector::back` to access the last element.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void printArray(std::vector<std::string> theArray);

int main()
{
   std::vector<std::string> data = { "Hi","my","name","is","John"};

   printArray(data);

   system("PAUSE");
   return 0;
}

void printArray(std::vector<std::string> theArray) {
   for (const auto &element : theArray) {
      cout << element << endl;
   }
   cout << "Last: " << theArray.back() << endl;
}
```

`vector` is part of standard c++. You should use containers if you learn c++. An alternative to `std::vector` is `std::array`. Both store the size so you don't need to pass it as an argument to a function.

Comment: Thank you @Thomas Sablik for your effort. It seems like true but I can't use <string> in my project.

Comment: You used string in your example. I didn't add it.

Comment: I mean I can't use <vector> in my project

Comment: Why not? It is standard c++. If you learn c++ you should use stl containers and avoid old c style code with arrays.

Comment: Why the prejudice against vector in these courses?  I just don't get it.

Comment: Ok, than use another solution. But remember to never again write such code as it is not c++ style and error-prone. You have to store and pass the size everywhere you use that array. If you write such code in a job interview you can go home.

Comment: @Asell the problem with this approach of teaching is that the only reasonable thing to do when you cannot use `std::vector` is to write a replacement for it. Falling back to using c-arrays and passing them together with their size is never acceptable in c++. We wont solve this here, as its your prof we would have to convince that his teaching is crap, though you should at least be aware that using `std::string` while disallowing `std::vector` is crude non-sense

Comment: I think the prof may be a Java, C# or similar teacher.  That's the only reason I can give why the prof would believe a `std::string` is "natural" since all of those languages have strings out of the box, while `vector` is something "special" and "third-party".

Answer (score 1):

You don't need loop through all elements,

```
string lastElement=theArray[sizeofarray-1]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @crack_iT